# Why do I get the error 'Attempt to get non existent parameter "count-1"' when I use HTML::Template?

Tags: perl

I am trying to populate an HTML drop down list using [HTML::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template):

```
use HTML::Template;
my @ARRAY = ("count1,count2,count3");
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'test.tmpl');
$template->param( COUNT => \@ARRAY );
print $template->output();
```

Here's my template file (test.tmpl):

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
<select><TMPL_LOOP NAME="COUNT"><option value="count1"><TMPL_VAR NAME=NAME><TMPL_VAR NAME=VALUES></option></TMPL_LOOP></select>                                
</div>
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Attempt to get nonexistent parameter 'count1,count2,count3' -
this parameter name doesn't match any declarations in the template file
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you ran and the template you used? You don't even set `@TOTAL`.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question.  I am not sure I've properly used that array values at html template file. Please suggest the proper way to use the array on html template on above select class. Thank you

Comment: Do you really want the array to have just one element?

Comment: Hi, I actualy want the entire array to be listed in the drop down list( count1 , count2, count3)  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what result you want from this, but each element of a `TMPL_LOOP` parameter must be a *hash* containing one or more values. Within the `<TMPL_LOOP NAME="COUNT">` element you can call out elements of each hash using `<TMPL_VAR NAME=FIELD>` where `FIELD` is the name of the hash key that must appear in every element of the array

If I combine this template

```xml
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <select>
        <TMPL_LOOP NAME="COUNT">
            <option value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=VALUE>"><TMPL_VAR NAME=NAME></option>
        </TMPL_LOOP>
    </select>                                
</div>
```

with this Perl code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use HTML::Template;

my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'test.tmpl');

my @count = (
    { name => 'count1', value => 1 },
    { name => 'count2', value => 2 },
    { name => 'count3', value => 3 },
);

$template->param( COUNT => \@count );

print $template->output, "\n";
```

then this is the result. I assume you were hoping for something similar

```xml
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <select>

            <option value="1">count1</option>

            <option value="2">count2</option>

            <option value="3">count3</option>

    </select>                                
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, thanks for your reply. I am trying to get those values in  the drop down list . now after using the above code, I am not getting any error, but none of the values are showing in the drop down list. Thank you

Comment: Hi ,  I am trying to list count1 , count2 , count3 values in the dropdown list. now the dropdown list is shows empty. however, the page source shows the values.  Please suggest how to list those values in the dropdown list. Thank you

Comment: At a guess you've not understood that `<TMPL_VAR  NAME=VALUE>` and `<TMPL_VAR  NAME=NAME>`. Must tie up with the `value` and `name` hash keys in the `@count` array. But it's impossible to diagnose your code without seeing it. You must ask another question

Comment: Hi, I've used the same above code in the script and template file.  if I right click page source as it shows  <option value="1">count1</option>  and 2,3 like these , however in the cgi page drop down list shows empty. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the loop variable needs to be a AoH. Based on your template, it specifically needs to loop like

```
my @ARRAY = (
    { NAME => 'count1', VALUES => 1 },
    { NAME => 'count2', VALUES => 2 },
    { NAME => 'count3', VALUES => 3 },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore these errors if there are fields in your result set that you want to skip in the template...

```
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => $filename, die_on_bad_params => 0);
```

Use with caution!