# How to get an array values in the dropdown in Perl CGI HTML template?

Tags: perl

Please suggest how to get array values in the dropdown list using HTML template.

```
use HTML::Template;
open (FL, "<file.txt"); 

#(file.txt values are below)
#count1
#count2
#count3
#count4
#count5 ## samples

my @TOTAL = <FL>; 

foreach $count(@TOTAL) {
    chomp $count;
    $template->param( COUNT => [{name => $count}]); # here I am getting only one value in  the drop down menu (count1 value only)
}
```

I am expecting the values like below, so the drop down will list all the values.

```
$template->param(COUNT => [{name => $count1}, {name => $count2}, {name => $count3}, {name => $count4}]);

print $template->output, "\n";
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and pay attention to proper formatting. It's very hard to read.

Comment: Please explain what module you're using and provide some context, like showing where `$template` comes from. Not everybody has read your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34701433/176646) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34682634/176646) on the same topic.

Comment: Hi. I've edited my question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`map` it](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), then there's no need for a loop.

```
$template->param( 
  COUNT => [ 
    map { 
      { name => $_ } 
    } @TOTAL 
  ]
);
```

The outer `{}` is for the *block* that `map` needs, and the inner `{}` is the hash reference.

But don't forget to [`chomp` your input](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

Comment: Hi. sorry about that. I've accepted the answer. Thank you